# custom sound not working in unnotificationrequest ios 10 objC

Tags: ios, objective-c, unnotificationrequest

custom sound not working in unnotificationrequest - iOS 10

I tried :

### [UNNotificationSound soundNamed:@"Alarm.mp3"]

or

### [UNNotificationSound soundNamed:@"Alarm"]

and the file is exist in bundle or Library/Sounds
but always played default sound when app is in background.
is anybody know why?

Answer (score 3):

It appears there's a bug in iOS 10. If you delete your app from the iPhone or Simulator and install fresh, your custom sounds should work fine. It's only when you **re-run** the app from Xcode do the custom sounds stop working.

It also appears that updates to an app through TestFlight/HockeyApp and presumably from the App Store itself will break the custom sounds. I'd count on Apple fixing this in future releases.

There's a conversation about this bug on the [Apple Developer Forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/49512), and multiple radars have been filed.

Comment: This also seems to applies to token recognition. I have to delete my ios10-based test device app every single time i debug in order for it to process notifs properly. If i don't, i see "completely unknown token" errors.

Radar: 28789788 {which is getting NO love at all..}

Comment: so basically the real users won't have any problem and this is just a development problem? Also which ones does it have to be? alarm.aiff/caf or just alarm?